# Replace name element using regex

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to replace this "iwdnowfreedom[body_style][var]" with this "iwdnowfreedom_body_style_var" in the name attributes of a variable. There could be several array keys but for my situation stripping them out shouldn't result in any issues.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
$pattern = '/name\\s*=\\s*["\'](.*?)["\']/i';
$replacement = 'name="$2"';
$fixedOutput = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $input);

return $fixedOutput;
```

How can I fix this to work properly?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want to replace from and to?

Comment: Why not just do str_replace on [ and ]?  The last occurrence could be ignored...

Comment: You sample code doesn;t seem to be relevant to you text description.  I don't see "name" in your text description at all, yet you use it isnyou code pattern.

Comment: We are changing the name html tag which looks like name=NAME" . We want to use regex instead of string replace because there are multiple values for name and we need to replace them all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using the build in str_replace function to achieve what you are looking for (assuming there are no nested bracked like "test[test[key]]"):

```
$str = "iwdnowfreedom[body_style][var]";
echo trim( str_replace(array("][", "[", "]"), "_", $str), "_" );
```

or if you prefer regex (nested brackets work fine with this method):

```
$input = "iwdnowfreedom[body_style][var]";
$pattern = '/(\[+\]+|\]+\[+|\[+|\]+)/i';
$replacement = '_';
$fixedOutput = trim( preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $input), "_" );

echo $fixedOutput;
```

I think you also meant that you might have a string such as

```
<input id="blah" name="test[hello]" />
```

and to parse the name attribute you could just do:

```
function parseNameAttribute($str)
{
    $pos = strpos($str, 'name="');

    if ($pos !== false)
    {
        $pos += 6; // move 6 characters forward to remove the 'name="' part

        $endPos = strpos($str, '"', $pos); // find the next quote after the name="

        if ($endPos !== false)
        {
            $name = substr($str, $pos, $endPos - $pos); // cut between name=" and the following "

            return trim(preg_replace('/(\[+\]+|\]+\[+|\[+|\]+)/i', '_', $name), '_');
        }
    }

    return "";
}
```

OR

```
function parseNameAttribute($str)
{
    if (preg_match('/name="(.+?)"/', $str, $matches))
    {
        return trim(preg_replace('/(\[+\]+|\]+\[+|\[+|\]+)/i', '_', $matches[1]), '_');
    }

    return "";
}
```

Comment: How can we make sure it checks that it only replaces inside the HTMl name tag? The string won't always be iwdnowfreedom[body_style][var] so have to make sure it works for anything inside name=""

Comment: Just create some sort of html helper function that sanitizes the string. So make like "removeBrackets($nameStr)" and then when you output the name, you run the $nameStr through your function.

Comment: Can't do it as it's from a wordpress theme function so have to replace it after the fact or permanently modify 10 different functions (around 800 lines).

Comment: Sorry i'm still not 100% what you mean, but i edited my answer to (hopefully) help what you need. Sorry if that isn't what you are trying to do.